# WebApiCodeGen Client Customizations

Tags: c#, client, customization, auto-generate

I am using https://webapiclientgen.codeplex.com/ to auto generate a client that will access an Asp.net WebAPI service I have written.

The client generates just fine but I would like to customize the generation so that it will add code that will automatically add an auth header to the request. If I add the code myself to the generated client it will be overwritten if/when the client is regenerated. It is possible that someone else will need to regenerate one and forget to add the header additions again.

Is there a way to do this? I cant imagine the framework would be so constricting. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is apparently about TypeScript codes generated. The latest release 1.9.2 supports auth with bearer token out of the box for TypeScript codes generated, while the first release had already supported bearer token out of the box for C#. You may check this https://webapiclientgen.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DemoWebApi/Scripts/tests/demo.tests.ts to see how to call Web API decorated by AuthorizeAttribute.